# Process substitution - tr says 'extra operand /dev/fd/63'

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I'm struggling to understand process substitution.  As far as I know,

```
echo abcd | tr -d 'b'
tr -d 'b' <(echo abcd)
```

should both give the same output.  But the first one works (output is 'acd') but the second says

```
tr: extra operand '/dev/fd/63'
```

Why is this?  Doesn't tr just receive 'abcd' through the pipe, and not '/dev/fd/63' as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way process substitution works is, Bash will replace `<(echo abcd)` with (for example) `/dev/fd/63`, which most common *nix utilities will treat like a filename and open instead of standard input. `tr`, however, does *not* accept a filename argument; it *only* takes standard input.

To pass the result of `<(echo abcd)` on standard input, you can use another `<`:

```
tr -d b < <(echo abcd)
```